# Find log file path through debugging?

Tags: java, docker, logging, slf4j

I have been recently provided with a large code base to work on that is running inside a docker container.

There are various log.debug statement in the code but I am unable to find where the log is getting printed.

I tried to find xml file or properties file in the where the configuration for the logger might be written but unable to find such files.

I am able to remote debug the application through application and able to inspect the logger object. Is there a way/expression/code that I can run to give me the location of log file path through debugging.

The logger being used is slf4j.Logger and during debugging i found that class file for logger is "ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger"

Let me know if there are some things I can look for to see where logs get printed.
I have the source code and can modify the application and run it if needed.

Comment: Did you check your jvm parameters ? I usually put the log configuration file location in there with help of "-Dlogback.configurationFile"

Comment: @Zackorrigan Thanks for the tip, I checked start script which runs the JVM i.e java command.  It has YAML file supplied for configuration I am looking more into it.